# How to install multiple openerp version on ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: installation, odoo, ubuntu-10.04, multiple-versions

anyone know how to install multiple openerp version inside ubuntu 10.04 LTS ? i need to support 3 version of openerp which are 6.0.4, 6.1 & 7.0 is it possible to install all versions inside 1 OS ? and how do i manage so that i can easily switch version to run openERP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run different OpenERP servers on different ports.

For example:

**6.0:** `--xmlrpc-port=9091 --netrpc-port=9090 --no-xmlrpcs`

**6.1:** `--xmlrpc-port=9094 --netrpc-port=9093`

**7.0:** `--xmlrpc-port=9096 --netrpc-port=9095`